# C++ struct error - error C2061: syntax error : identifier

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dev-c++

This is my code:

```
struct opts
{
   int a;
   int b;
};
class myclass
{
  private:
           opts options;
 public:
       void afunction();
}

//myclass.cpp
void myclass::afunction()
{
     if options.a==1
           //do something
}
```

When I compile it I am getting the follwoing error.

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier options
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You're missing a `;` after `class myclass {...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if options.a==1
```

is wrong. The condition has to be surrounded by parenthesis.

```
 if (options.a==1)
```

Comment: This is of course another problem with the code, but it's weird that it's accepted, since the issue pointed out by DCoder in a comment seems to be the root cause of the error.